# Panic stack trace: How the values are mapped to a function's arguments?

Tags: go

Looking at the last line there ".Number(..."

Is it possible to discern the arguments to the method `Number()` from those hex numbers?

It would be a help, without hitting the debugger too often.

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 19 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc042046340)
    C:/Go/src/testing/testing.go:622 +0x2a4
panic(0x523e20, 0x5df810)
    C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2dd
util.(*NumberEngine).Number(0xc042066150, 0xf4698, 0xa, 0xc042b2a870, 0xa)
```

edit: including the full signature of method

```
func (fe *NumberEngine) Number(num int) Number {
```

edit: including the definition of Number

```
type Power struct{ Prime, Exp int }
type Number []Power
```

Comment: It might be, but we can't help you without the code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660897/unknown-field-in-panic-stack-trace.

Comment: That's not the full method signature, because you haven't provided the definition of the `Number` type, but the `num` argument from the stack is `0xf4698`

Answer (score 3):

In the "reference" implementation (that one, dubbed `gc` and available for download at https://golang.org):

- The first argument to a method is the method's receiver.

  In your case it's a pointer receiver, so `0xc042066150` is the
  address of that `NumberEngine` instance in memory.
- All the arguments are passed on the stack — from left to right.

  - The fields of compound types such as `struct`s appear in the order they are defined in the type.
  - `string`s and slices are compound types — of two and three fields each,
    respectively: pointer + length and pointer + length + capacity.

For more info, we need the signature of the `util.(*NumberEngine).Number` method, and the definitions of any custom types it uses, if any.

Comment: the signature is just an int -> util.(*NumberEngine).Number(num int)

Comment: @RiyazMansoor, I can't beleive it has a single argument of type `int`. Please double check.

Comment: have updated original post with full method signature.

Comment: @kostix: return parameters are also allocated on the stack (I forgot to mention that in my linked answer, but probably should)

Comment: @RiyazMansoor, please also provide the definition of `Number`

Comment: Hi. Updated OP with definition of Number. This is getting really interesting now :)

Comment: @RiyazMansoor: it's not _that_ interesting, because return parameters are not initialized, so the last 3 numbers are pretty much meaningless, but it does corroborate the stack is what is expected from your example.

Comment: @JimB Hmmm, so how to find the int passed to the method from the panic stack trace ?

Comment: @RiyazMansoor, just like in the answer I linked in the other comments, and in this answer. The int passed in is 0xf4698

Comment: Thanks @JimB @ kostix - this would save a lot time for me.  Quick question, same for floats? what about strings? would it be address of the string?

Comment: @RiyazMansoor: The arguments to the function are printed out, which would include floats, which again is explained in more detail in the answer I linked above. String are 2 word headers, so you can't see the actual string contents in the argument, just the length and data pointer.