# What do these numbers in a stack trace mean?

Tags: go

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0x467a05, 0xc000000180, 0x200000003)
        /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x80
runtime/debug.PrintStack()
        /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:16 +0x18
main.test3()
        /tmp/test_stacktrace.go:18 +0x101
```

How do you understand these words as follow?

> 0x467a05, 0xc000000180, 0x200000003
> +0x80  +0x18  +0x101

Comment: all these words lie in code snappet

Comment: For the old style arguments, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660897/unknown-field-in-panic-stack-trace/47662796#47662796

Answer (score 7):

Those are the raw (computer-instruction-level) values of various arguments passed to various functions.  Well, that is, the ones in parentheses—the `+0x101` is the program counter offset in the machine code.

To make sense of them, you must look at the raw computer code, or use a debugger.  Debuggers use trace information that the compiler leaves behind to translate from "computer register `%rax` holds `0x467a05`" (or whatever) into "variable x holds value ..." (for some value, maybe a string for instance).

If you're not sure what they represent, concentrate instead just on the names and line numbers in the stack trace.  You were in function `main.test3` at line 18 when you called function `PrintStack` in the runtime code.

Comment: It always has 3 parameters with runtime/debug.Stack,  What do each parameter stand for ?

Comment: @wate That's because `debug.PrintStack` calls `debug.Stack` with those three parameters. Take a look at the [source code for runtime/debug/stack.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/runtime/debug/stack.go;l=15). See that `PrintStack` calsl `os.Stderr.Write(Stack())`. That's a call to the `Stack()` function, which returns `[]byte`. To return `[]byte`, the call to `Stack` passes those three parameters, into which `Stack` writes its return value.

Comment: Go's parameter and return mechanisms are peculiar: you won't find this technique used by C compilers, for instance. The exact mechanism is not prescribed by the language and may change from one Go release to the next.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the output of stack traces has just changed (with Go 1.17): https://golang.org/doc/go1.17#compiler

Comment: @jub0bs: ah, nice, I'd been hoping for such a change. Makes life a little harder for the GC, perhaps (depending on how they implement "last live pointer value is function argument") and puts emphasis on the "not prescribed by the language" part above.